# Can I run Bottle.py on my Apache server without disrupting my PHP apps?

Tags: python, apache2, bottle

I'm antsy to get Python running on my webserver after just recently picking it up.

I chose Bottle.py because it looks simple, accessible, and contained. I have very little experience with or knowledge of how exactly webservers work (how to mess with them) and I'm reluctant to play with my server's Apache if I don't need to since it hosts a very active message board already.

Bottle's documentation seemed to assume a step or two of server/python understanding that I don't have, as I'm not even sure where to put the actual routes/website content once I already have bottle.py copied over to my doc root. Or how the server knows to run bottle (or execute python) when I go to "mydomain.com".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run it in a WSGI container such as [mod_wsgi](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/).

Comment: I just did this for "pylons". The most confusing thing about the documentation was all the options to sort through.  However the bottle documentation for mod_wsgi seems pretty straightforward http://bottle.paws.de/docs/dev/tutorial_app.html#server-setup.  As it mentions mod_wsgi might already be installed.  You can get the module list with "apachectl -M".

Comment: http://bottle.paws.de/docs/dev/tutorial_app.html is an inch more verbose than the http://bottle.paws.de/docs/dev/tutorial.html I was looking at (I understand it a little better). The <VirtualHost> block broke my local Apache, which is why I hesitated to try it on my webserver, but I wasn't even aware that mod_wsgi could simply not be installed. I'll try again.

Answer (score 2):

You can also run Apace as a proxy to your application. I believe using [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_proxy.html) would get you there. I myself run a nginx front end as reverse proxy to a bottle application running on bjoern. Bjoern itself is quite capable of running the bottle app, so I didn't want to use mod_wsgi, and similar stuff.